# convert array of values column to string column (containing serialised json)

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Background**

I am flattening a nested schema for a given Spark DataSet by first producing a mapping of leaf nodes/types from the `StructType` from `dataset.schema()`, then using `col.alias(...)` and `select(reAliasedCols)` to produce a flattened dataset. Eg:

**Issue**

Instead of pivoting/exploding array type fields, I would like to serialize them to a JSON string.

This approach seems to almost work using the [to_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_json-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) function for array serialisation as in the following contrived example: `dataset.select(to_json(dataset.col("item.messages")).alias("item_messages"))`.

Unfortunately, this fails for columns containing arrays of primitives (arrays of structs/objects are serialized correctly) as follows:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'structstojson(`item`.`messages`)'
   due to data type mismatch: Input type array<string>
   must be a struct, array of structs or a map or array of map.;;
```

It appears `to_json` does not support serialization of arrays of primitives, supporting only "*StructType, ArrayType of StructTypes, a MapType or ArrayType of MapTypes*" (in spite of [SPARK-21513: SQL to_json should support all column types](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21513)

**Example datasets/schemas:**

Given a dataset of string records such as:

```
{
  "item": {
    "messages": [
      "test",
      "test2",
      "test3"
    ]
  }
}
```

Which when loaded with `read().json(dataSetOfJsonStrings)` produces a schema like:

```
root
 |-- item: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- messages: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How might ArrayType columns be transformed to serialised json? Eg, this schema:

```
root
 |-- item: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- messages: string (nullable = true)
```

Which might be written out in JSON format like:

```
{
  "item": {
    "messages": "[\"test\",\"test2\",\"test3\"]"
  }
}
```

Note: Example output not flattened, just illustrating to_json() usage.

**Question:**

Is it possible to serialize an array of primitives in this kind of transformation?

I would like to preserve the structure of any array type column, instead of for example, wrapping array type columns in a struct just to allow serialisation via `to_json`:

```
to_json(struct(dataset.col("item.messages"))).alias("item_messages")
```

Which produces something like this:

```
{
  "item": {
    "messages": "{ \"messages\": [\"test\",\"test2\",\"test3\"] }"
  }
}
```